# Combination of negative term in negative Binomial expression.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

I saw the formula of negative binomial expression [here](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/binomialProofNegativeIntegers2.gif)
Here I know that in common notion is that the numbers in [large bracket](https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2012/12_w51/623555/two-big-brackets2.JPG)  just after sign of summation represents combination of below w.r.t to above.Here can you tell me how do we involve negative number in combination & do (-n)Ck.Means how can we find combination of negative number (-n) here

Comment: Any thoughts/comments/questions on my answer?

Comment: Earth to Brijesh, come in, please.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ and $k$ are positive integers with $k\le n$ then the formula $${n\choose k}={n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)\over k!}$$ has a combinatorial interpretation as the number of ways of choosing $k$ things from $n$ things. When $n$ is not a positive integer with $k\le n$, the formula no longer has that combinatorial interpretation, but it still indicates a legal computation, and is taken to be the definition of $n\choose k$. And even though it doesn't have that combinatorial interpretation, it still has many uses in combinatorics and elsewhere (to begin with, in the general form of the Binomial Theorem).

Comment: I doubt you'll see this but isn't k supposed to still be positive? so k shouln't be less than or equal to n when n is negative

Comment: @sni, I didn't state it explicitly, but, yes, $k$ is meant to be a nonnegative integer, and the formula works whether or not $k\le n$.